# Async function import return not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have problem with the async function in Node.js when importing

Here is dbandauth.js

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
// const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const newsRouter = express.Router();

async function consoleTest(){
    //this function test the database to ouput something
    let mariadbcon = mariadb.createPool({
        host: 'somehost',
        user: '*****user',
        password: '****password',
        connectionLimit: 7,
        database: '*****db'
    });
    let conn;
    try {
        conn = await mariadbcon.getConnection();
        const rows = await conn.query("SELECT * FROM `accounts`");
        console.log(rows);
    } catch (err){
        throw err;
    } finally {
        if (conn) return conn.end();
    };
}
module.exports.consoleTest = consoleTest;
```

[image]
Below is my passport.js after

```
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const isValid = require('../../lib/passwordUtils');
const dataUser = require('./dbandauth')

dataUser.consoleTest();
```

[image]
When I call that consoleTest() with Node.js from passport.js file, it returns "dataUser.consoleTest() is not a function", but when I ran from the original file, it returns data. I don't know what is wrong with that import.

Comment: Looks like it should work… but if it isn't a function… what is it? Do some debugging. At least `console.log` the value.

Comment: i am searching other topic about async await;  it should work but i don't know why it return that error when calling it from other file. what about return value ? @Quentin

Comment: What return value? The error says it isn't a function. If it isn't a function you can't call it and get a return value. We still don't know what it is because you completely ignored every part of my previous comment except my handle.

Comment: i add 2 picture when running seperately, the one on the passport show the err. @Quentin